# Custom domain mapping on Python Flask SaaS App

Tags: python, flask, heroku, dns

I'm building a relatively straightforward SaaS application using Python/Flask.

Each user in the application will be assigned a subdomain of the applications domain (eg. `subdomain.appdomain.com`). However, I'm wanting to include the functionality for paid users to map their custom domain as an alias to the subdomain in their DNS.

So that when a user visits `customdomain.com` it serves the same content as if they were visiting `subdomain.appdomain.com`.

I can seem to find any material on how to achieve this functionality, so any help would be appreciated.